# How to turn off the help hints in git output?

Tags: git

I'm using git in the terminal and know most of the commands I need by heart. Therefore I would like to suppress the "help hints" in the output, i.e. all the text in parenthesis starting with `(use "git ...`) to make the output less verbose.

I know of the flags `--short` and `--porcelain`, but then the output is less readable on a quick glance IMHO.

Is there a way to keep the default formatting of the output but without the help text?

**Example:**

```sh
git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.

Changes not staged for commit:

    modified:   file1.txt
    modified:   file2.txt

Untracked files:

    untracked_file.txt

no changes added to commit
```

... instead of ...

```sh
git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1.txt
    modified:   file2.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

    untracked_file.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: See if `git config --global status.hints false` does the trick.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but some more searching with that information in mind, lead me to this `git config --global advice.statusHints false` which worked

Comment: Agh, sorry, I got it wrong, I found the setting in my user file and when I googled the exact syntax of the config command my brain decided to forgot half of what I read. I guess it's time for bed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Git offered enabling/disabling advice by using the 'advice.*' key in the configuration. See `git help config` for more information or the [online manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-advice). The following 14 variables exist:

```
advice.pushUpdateRejected
advice.pushNonFFCurrent
advice.pushNonFFMatching
advice.pushAlreadyExists
advice.pushFetchFirst
advice.pushNeedsForce
advice.statusHints
advice.statusUoption
advice.commitBeforeMerge
advice.resolveConflict
advice.implicitIdentity
advice.detachedHead
advice.amWorkDir
advice.rmHints
```

You can set them with `git config --global advice.*`. For example `git config --global advice.statusHints false`. Note that I have not seen a way to disable all the same time.

Comment: This improved my git experience a lot.  Thanks

Comment: `git help --config | grep -P '^advice\.' | …`

Comment: Not every hint can be disabled with the advice keys, you also need to `git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
` to set a default branch to stop the advice when creating a repository

Comment: Could you maybe also post the link to the man page?

Answer (score 2):

The `git config --global advice.* false` mentioned in the other answers gain a new feature with Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [batch 12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc7ee2e5e16f0d1e710ef8fab3db59ab11f2bbe7): all conditional "`advice`" messages show how to turn them off, which becomes repetitive.
Setting `advice.*` configuration explicitly on now omits the instruction part.

See [commit d919965](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d919965af116d145de40853caf0e4228c97da325) (15 Jan 2024) by [Rubén Justo (`rjusto`)](https://github.com/rjusto).
See [commit 8cf646f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8cf646faac355fb44199793fe1a080b82abffc29) (16 Jan 2024) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e14c0ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e14c0ab176054ec47afd1e85445277cacfc060a3), 30 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`advice`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d919965af116d145de40853caf0e4228c97da325): allow disabling the automatic hint in `advise_if_enabled()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Rubén Justo</sup>

> Using `advise_if_enabled()` to display an advice will automatically include instructions on how to disable the advice, alongside the main advice:
>
> ```
> hint: use --reapply-cherry-picks to include skipped commits
> hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.skippedCherryPicks false"
> ```
>
> To do so, we provide a knob which can be used to disable the advice.
>
> But also to tell us the opposite: to show the advice.
>
> Let's not include the deactivation instructions for an advice if the user explicitly sets its visibility.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d919965af116d145de40853caf0e4228c97da325/Documentation/config/advice.txt#L3-L5):

> When left unconfigured, Git will give the message
> alongside instructions on how to squelch it.
> You can tell Git
> that you do not need the help message by setting these to 'false'.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add something like the following snippet into your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[advice]                                                                        
    statusHints = false                                                         
    pushUpdateRejected = false                                                  
    pushNonFFCurrent = false                                                    
    pushNonFFMatching = false                                                   
    pushAlreadyExists = false                                                   
    pushFetchFirst = false                                                      
    pushNeedsForce = false                                                      
    statusHints = false                                                         
    statusUoption = false                                                       
    commitBeforeMerge = false                                                   
    resolveConflict = false                                                     
    implicitIdentity = false                                                    
    detachedHead = false                                                        
    amWorkDir = false                                                           
    rmHints = false
```

Answer (score 0):

@somnium created a list, here is a way to disable all advice globally:

```
man git-config | sed '0,/advice.*/d;/^       \w/,$d' | grep '^           \w\+$' | xargs -i% git config --global --add advice.% false
```

This is kinda brittle due to reliance on the man-page format, but should work reliably.

Comment: `git help --config | grep -P '^advice\.' | …`

Comment: The above code returns 4 less variables than `git help --config | ..` as of git 2.39.2